# How to translate a txt into csv or excel using python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a txt doc likes this:

```
id=xxx+++xxxx@xxx.com>>
type : Uninstall<<1>>identifiant : com.xxx.android<<2>>

type : New install<<1>>nom : xxx<<2>>

identifiant : com.xxx.android<<4>>

permission : android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE<<6>>

permission : android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE<<6>
```

I am supposed to write a program to translate these informations into a readable Excel or Csv file.
I am new to python and I even know nothing about programming.
I have been learning python for a week and I have learnt the basic.

I wanted to creat a csv file from infos above :

```
id, install, app, READ_PHONE_STATE, READ_PHONE_STATE...

xxx, 0or1, nameofapp, 0or1, 0or1...
```

I tried:

`import re`

`appinfo = open('chemin'+'app_info'+'.asc', 'r')`

```
print appinfo
```

`<<id=xxx+++xxx@gmail.com>>`

at first I want to seperate id and mail and put them in 2 colonne in my future csv file so  I tried:

```
searchObj = re.search( r'<<(.*)\\+\\+\\+(.*?)>>', identifiant_mail, re.M|re.I)
    if searchObj:
print searchObj.group(1)
print searchObj.groupe(2)
```

Which doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should parse the file. You can use regex. In python [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) library is used for regex operation. Parse each column line by line and write it a file with using [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library.